# Negative value in Date.setSeconds()

Tags: javascript, date

Have the following code in any browser console:

```js
const d = new Date("Tue Aug 22 2023 14:33:37 GMT+0300"); // returns undefined

d // Tue Aug 22 2023 14:33:37 GMT+0300 

d.setSeconds(-60); // 1692703920000

d // Tue Aug 22 2023 14:32:00 GMT+0300
```

At last line, I was expecting `d` to be `Tue Aug 22 2023 14:32:37 GMT+0300`

Why does negative value passed to `setSeconds()` break the timestamp?

---

Note on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds#description

> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setSeconds() attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly. For example, if you use 100 for secondsValue, the minutes stored in the Date object will be incremented by 1, and 40 will be used for seconds.

Comment: "*Why does negative value passed to setSeconds() break the timestamp?*" because the date object works as it's implemented, not as you want it to?

Comment: Both, please see the edit

Comment: Sure, I saw it. I don't see where it says that negative values would work like you expect them to.

Comment: "If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setSeconds() attempts to" set the seconds value to the specific time you gave it.  It does *not* try to use the input as an increment, which is what you're trying to achieve with negative numbers; it tries to use it as a literal value.

Comment: this method does not add nor subtract seconds from your date. It SETS seconds. If you use `d.setSeconds(1);` it will give you 14:33:01, hence, if you use `d.setSeconds(-60);` it will give you 14:32:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, [*setSeconds*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.setseconds) sets the seconds component of the time to the supplied value.

So given `…setSeconds(-60)` for a time of 14:33:37, the seconds component of the time is set to -60, which is effectively 14:33:-60. That evaluates to 14:32:00 (i.e. 60 seconds before 14:33).

If you want to subtract 60 seconds, you need to do:

```
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() - 60);
```

which in the example will set the time to 14:32:37, e.g.

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setHours(14,33,37,0);
console.log(d.toTimeString());

d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() - 60);
console.log(d.toTimeString());
```